# MongoDB no inicia en mi contenedor Docker. (Quiero ejecutar un binario)

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

Pregunté algo similar la otra vez y una persona muy amable me ayudó, pero me surgió otro problema.
Tengo mi Dockerfile. Escrito de la siguiente manera:

```
###Download MONGO (with Ubuntu)
FROM mongo:latest

###Create an App directory
RUN mkdir /app

###Nos situamos en el directorio
WORKDIR /app

###Copiamos el binario 'general' dentro del directorio.
COPY general .

###Update the OS ubuntu image
#RUN apt-get -y update

###Install packages
###Instalo curl para poder hacer peticiones get dentro de la consola,
###Posteriormente expondré el puerto y las haré en Postman.
#RUN apt-get -y install curl


###NECESITO QUE CARGUE MONGO Y EJECUTAR EL BINARIO: ./general
#ENTRYPOINT [ "./general" ]
#CMD ["./general"]
#RUN ./general
```

Lo que aparece ahí, se ejecuta perfectamente y hace lo que espero: me copia el binario dentro de un directorio. Al correr el contenedor, se ejecuta Mongo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo accedo a la **consola de ubuntu** que proporciona Mongo, puedo correr y ejecutar sin problema el **archivo binario**, hacer peticiones get y post (que modifican la base de datos), etc. **(TODAVÍA NO CREE LA PERSISTENCIA DE DATOS)**

**EL PROBLEMA LLEGA CUANDO QUIERO EJECUTAR EL ARCHIVO BINARIO AUTOMATICAMENTE.**
En el Dockerfile, se muestra que en las lineas 23, 24 y 25, probé de varias formas.
Con Entrypoint y CMD me lanzá el error que quiero solucionar. (con RUN no me crea el contenedor)

```
###NECESITO QUE CARGUE MONGO Y EJECUTAR EL BINARIO: ./general
#ENTRYPOINT [ "./general" ]
#CMD ["./general"]
#RUN ./general
```

Al construir el contenedor y correrlo con Entrypoint o CMD lanza el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
2022-03-23T12:31:26.929Z        
ERROR   database@v0.0.0-20220314180949-692d24e91eb6/mongo.go:36 cannot PING the mongo server: 
server selection error: server selection timeout, current topology: { Type: Unknown,
Servers: [{ Addr: localhost:27017, Type: Unknown, Last error: connection() error occured 
during connection handshake: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: connect: connection refused }, ] }
```

**NO MUESTRA QUE SE INICIA LA BASE DE DATOS, directamente quiere correr el binario y va a lanzar ese error porque depende que exista una conexion activa a mongo.**

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberías [edit] tu pregunta y poner el código del dockerfile en  formato texto para que sea más sencillo de copiar y pegar si fuese necesario para realizar las pruebas [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando declaras tu **CMD** o **ENV** estás sobreescribiendo el comportamiento original de la imagen de la que estás *heredando* (mongo), que es precisamente crear y poner a escuchar a la base de MongoDB. [Lo puedes ver acá en su Dockerfile.](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/149ec872f80ca7790b053b72115f36ed2cef1117/4.0/Dockerfile#L119)

Si lo que quieres en conservar esa ejecución de la base y además ejecute tu archivo se me ocurre que puedes declarar un CMD que ejecute mongo en segundo plano (esto se logra usando las opciones *--fork* y *--syslog*):

```
CMD mongod --fork --syslog && ./general
```

Ahora, ten en cuenta que como ahora el último proceso es ejecutar tu archivo el contenedor se detendrá en cuanto acabe.

Espero esto te ayude.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me funcionó